# How to Parse HTML using JSoup

Tags: android, jsoup

please help me parse my special table html which contains many rows 
I try this code : `Elements table : doc.select(".titre2_tableau);` It give list of all elements like :

```
David 
13:30 
DELL  
Prof
13:55
SAM
14:15
HP
PROD
14:09 
peter
 13 :50
ACER
Beginner
14:12
```

But i need this list divided of group of 5 items like :

```
David - 13:3-0 – DELL – Prof - 13:55
SAM  - 14:15 – HP – PROD - 14:09
```

I think need a loop and iterator but i can't apply them for my case . Thanks for help

```
    <tr align="center">
      <td class="titre2_tableau" bgcolor="#F1FBFF">David</td>

      <td class="titre2_tableau" bgcolor="#F1FBFF">13:30</td>

      <td class="titre2_tableau" bgcolor="#F1FBFF">DELL</td>
      <td class="titre2_tableau" bgcolor="#F1FBFF">Prof</td>
      <td class="titre2_tableau" bgcolor="#F1FBFF"> 13:55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td class="titre2_tableau" bgcolor="#e0f4fd">SAM</td>

      <td class="titre2_tableau" bgcolor="#e0f4fd">14:15</td>

      <td class="titre2_tableau" bgcolor="#e0f4fd">HP</td>

      <td class="titre2_tableau" bgcolor="#e0f4fd">PROD</td>

      <td class="titre2_tableau" bgcolor="#e0f4fd"> 14:09</td>

    </tr>
```

Comment: you'd need to separate the titre2_tableau by their containers. e.g. find a titre_table, move up to its parent (`<tr>`) and then iterate the `<tr>`'s children.

Comment: how to do that because i'm beginner JSOUP  ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
final Elements tableElements = doc.select("tr");

for (Element element : tableElements) {

    String item = element.getElementsByClass("titre2_tableau").text();

}
```

The `tableElements` variable will contain each row of data (tr) while the for loop will grab each table data (td) from the corresponding row. You will have to play around with the loop to get exactly what you would like but the above code should get you started.

Comment: john thank you very much for help , if i want to save result in database and view the result which best solution sqlite and listview or webview ??